# What goes around comes around

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Speak and I shout

You say it once and I come aloud

For I say alike

Invisible to your eyes,

Ears are my friend,

Because they understand.

To be my friend you have to take a hike,

Where its all crisp and white.

Tell me what am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's probably

> echo

Speak and I shout

> echo is a sound

You say it once and I come aloud 
For I say alike

> it just "repeats" what you say

Invisible to your eyes,

> sound is invisible

Ears are my friend,
Because they understand.

> but you hear the echo

To be my friend you have to take a hike,
Where its all crisp and white.

> the mountain is often a great place to hear your echoecho

Comment: The only bit that I find confusing is 'speak and I shout' as it implies the reply to your speech is louder, although this could be a quirk of the question. Nevertheless, +1 for a good answer, and one that sounds correct overall.

Comment: I also thought about that, I personally would have say it the other way, "shout and i speak" since echo can't be louder than the initial sound and usually we cause an echo by yelling. But the rest seemed to fit so well that I kept it

Comment: Agreed, @Kant1 , everything else fits perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

A slightly different take on Kant1's answer, I'd guess you are:

> **AN AVALANCHE**

Speak and I shout
You say it once and I come aloud

> A relatively small sound (like people speaking loudly) can trigger an avalanche in popular culture (e.g. Tintin in Tibet)
>  Yet, with that sound, the avalanche makes a much louder thundering sound

For I say alike
Invisible to your eyes,
Ears are my friend,
Because they understand.

> The start of an avalanche is often heard/felt than seen, especially if the mountainside is cloudy

To be my friend you have to take a hike,
Where its all crisp and white.

> You need a snowy mountain as one of the pre-requisites for an avalanche